# Долгая загрузка Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Недавно стал изучать Symfony 3 и столкнулся с такой проблемой: Либо при первом запуске, либо после длительного бездействия, сайт грузится около 20 сек. Отключение кэша не помогло. Профайлер показывает, что почти все время занимает инициализация контроллера. Хотя приложение не сложнее "Hello World". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: windows + vagrant?

Comment: можно посмотреть эти решения
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12905404/437763

Comment: @luchaninov, спасибо! Помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вещей, которые можно сделать.

#### Оптимизировать php.ini

- установить `realpath_cache_size = 4096k`
- установить `realpath_cache_ttl = 7200`
- выключить xdebug (можно проверить через phpinfo или в symfony profiler bar)
- включить APC

Не забудьте перезапустить Apache или php-fpm, чтобы применить изменения.

#### Кеширование Doctrine ORM metadata

В `app/config/config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver: apc
```

#### Не использовать виртуальные машины

Файловые системы виртуальных машин медленно работают с общими папками. Symfony интенсивно использует `APP/var/cache` в dev-окружении.

Если без виртуальных машин не обойтись, можно перенести эту папку из общей папки в папку только в виртуальной машине или вообще в память - `/dev/shm`. При этом IDE не сможет получить к ним доступ, чтобы делать красивое автодополнение, зная полный контейнер. Можно первый раз кеш делать в обычной папке, а потом уже в `/dev/shm/`. Чтобы обновить локальный кеш, нужно или удалить его вручную или добавить в URL `?warmup=1`. В `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('cache/' . $this->getEnvironment());
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getVarOrShmDir('logs');
}

private function getVarOrShmDir($dir)
{
    $result = dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/' . $dir;

    if (
        in_array($this->environment, ['dev', 'test'], true) &&
        empty($_GET['warmup']) && // to force using real directory add ?warmup=1 to URL
        is_dir($result) && // first time create real directory, later use shm
        file_exists('/bin/mount') && shell_exec('mount | grep vboxsf') // only for VirtualBox
    ) {
        $result = '/dev/shm/' . 'YourAppName' . '/' . $dir . '/' . $this->getEnvironment();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Если используете Docker, то он выделяет относительно небольшой размер `/dev/shm`, но его можно переопределить опцией `shm_size` в `docker-compose.yml` или параметром `shm-size` при запуске docker из командной строки.

Похожий вопрос на stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905404/symfony2-slow-initialization-time

Answer (score 0):

Все проблемы с быстродействием из-за того, что папка **vendor** находится на хосте, а Virtualbox работает с файлами через vboxfs. И чем больше файлов в этой папке, тем медленнее работает сайт.

Эти проблемы возникают и с vagrant, и с docker, не зависимо от операционной системы. В vagrant под Linux можно было использовать nfs вместо vboxfs, но это не очень сильно ускоряет работу сайта

```
is_windows = (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "covex/symfony-ubuntu1604-x64"

    if not is_windows
        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", nfs: true, nfs_udp: false, nfs_version: 3
    end
end
```

Все остальные методы либо не удобные, как с отключением xdebug, либо костыли, потому что они не решают проблему использования vboxfs

Проблема решается перемещением папки **vendor** внутрь виртуальной машины в Vagrant или внутрь контейнера в Docker

Когда мы использовали Vagrant, мы в provision-скрипте конфигурировали composer, создавали simlink и запускали composer

```
if [ -d /home/vagrant/share ]; then
    composer config --file=/home/vagrant/.composer/config.json vendor-dir /home/vagrant/share/vendor
    composer config --global vendor-dir /home/vagrant/share/vendor
    if [ ! -d /vagrant/vendor ]; then
        ln -s /home/vagrant/share/vendor /vagrant/vendor
    fi
fi
```

Здесь возникает такая проблема, что код, спрятанный внутри виртуальной машины, не доступен для autocomplete для IDE. Это также решалось через provision-скрипт

- Содержимое папки vendor в виде phar архивов сохранялось на хост для IDE
- https://github.com/apnet/symfony-standard-edition/blob/master/vagrant/sync-vendor.php

Но vagrant сам по себе какой-то тормозной. Мы перешли на docker, проблему быстродействия решили схожим способом.

Answer (score 0):

Если на винде стоит докер, отключи WSL 2, и вкл поддержку hyper-v. Будет пархать как бабочка